# Mobile Application Stress Test

Tags: android, ios, testing, mobile, stress-testing

Are there any tools to do stress testing in iOS and Android applications? I want to test the application, to see if 50,000 people can use the app at the same time or if 50,000 people can use the web services the app is calling at the same time.

Comment: just test your server without the app, build somekind of script that call's those web sevices like 50000 times.

Comment: Agree with @RolfSmit, this belongs to the server part. Consider a tool like JMeter. http://jmeter.apache.org/

Answer (score 1):

`JMeter` should be your requirement and for profiling try `YourKit`. Hope this helps. Separately you can test your Web Service with `SOAP UI`

Comment: 2nd JMeter ...  was just getting ready to suggest the same.  you may have to write your own plugin

Comment: Sure thing that is advisable.

Answer (score 1):

Getting your hands on 50,000 Android/IOS devices is going to be challenging...or expensive...or both.  Assuming you've already tested the app on the device and performance is acceptable with minimal load on the server, you probably want to load test your server next. If your app uses HTTP to communicate with your server, then you can do it with a web load testing tool, such as our [Load Tester](https://www.webperformance.com/load-testing/) product. These will simulate the HTTP requests sent to the server by our app - thus you don't need to acquire 50k mobile devices. The LITE version is free with unlimited users, so you may be able to get some testing done with that before needing the advanced features in the PRO version. To be fair, there are other free load testing solutions available - search for web load testing software.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way, to use cloud services, which provides stress testing to [mobile applications](http://blazemeter.com/blog/load-testing-mobile-apps-made-easy). When  i [tested mobile applications](http://blazemeter.com/blog/load-testing-mobile-apps-made-easy), i used Apache Jmeter with Blazemeter and simulated load and stress  testing. In my Jmeter i configured the proxy to use with mobile device. Note that Android supports only HTTP proxy. If your application uses an HTTPS connection, then you may use an additional application that performs with HTTPS proxing.